# Multiple queue listeners will run the same job over multiple processes

Tags: php, laravel, beanstalkd

I have a simple web application that is written with the Laravel 4.2 framework. I have configured the Laravel queue component to add new queue items to a locally running beastalkd server.

Essentially, there is a POST route that will add an item to the beanstalkd tube.

I then have supervisord set up to run `artisan queue:listen` as three separate processes. The issue that I am seeing is that the different `queue:listen` processes will end up spawning anywhere between one to three `queue:worker` processes for just one inserted job.

The end result being that one job inserted into the queue is sometimes being processed by multiple workers at the same time, something I am obviously trying to avoid.

The job code is relatively simple:

```
<?php

use App\Repositories\URLRepository;

class ProcessDataJob {
    private $urls;

    public function __construct(URLRepository $urls)
    {
        $this->urls = $urls;
    }

    public function fire($job, $data)
    {
        $input = $data['post'];

        if (!isset($data['post']) && !is_array($data['post'])) {
            Log::error('[Job #'.$job->getJobId().'] $input was empty inside CreateAuditJob. Deleting job. Quitting. Bye!');
            $job->delete();
            return false;
        }

        //
        // ... code that will take a few hours to run.
        //

        $job->delete();
        Log::info('[Job #'.$job->getJobId().'] ProcessDataJob was successful, deleting the job!');
        return true;
    }
}
```

The fun part being that most of the (duplicated) queue workers fail when deleting the job with this left in the errorlog:

```
exception 'Pheanstalk_Exception_ServerException' with message 'Job 3248 NOT_FOUND: does not exist or is not reserved by client'
```

The ttr (Time to Run) is set to 172,800 seconds (or 48 hours), which is much larger then the time it would take for the job to complete.

Answer (score 4):

what's the job time_to_run when queued?  If running the job takes longer than time_to_run seconds, the job is automatically re-queued and becomes eligible to be run by the next worker.

A reserved job has time_to_run seconds to be deleted, released or touched.  Calling `touch()` restarts the timeout timer, so workers can use it to give themselves more time to finish.  Or use a large enough value when queueing.

I've found the beanstalkd protocol document helpful
https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/blob/master/doc/protocol.md

Comment: ok, so much for the easy solution.  Do the logs show that the dupliate jobs all start at the same time?  Or are they staggered?  It's possible there's some timeout in the app somewhere.  Else you might have to dig into the dispatch code to track down what it's doing.  I've written queuing systems (two in php, a third using beanstalk), but don't know laravel.

Comment: The duplicate jobs start __usually__ within 10 seconds of each other. There doesn't seem to be a timeout inside the app, especially with the beanstalk connection. No exceptions or errors are being thrown. I am thinking it might be a beanstalk bug.

Comment: 10 seconds is a long time... how weird.  Can you instrument the dispatch?  just to log the job id returned by beanstalk reserve()?  Bisection search, either narrow it to beanstalk or to the app.  For timeout, I was thinking of a built-in "declare error after 10 minutes" configured max-run-time type of thing

Comment: Ah, no timeouts have been set. A telnet to the beanstalk server running reserve on two separate connections returns the same data, so I am fairly sure it's a beanstalkd issue.

Comment: yikes  what version of beanstalk?

Comment: beanstalkd 1.9. v1.10 is the latest, but looking at the diff (https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/compare/v1.9...v1.10) I can't see anything that would change the behaviour that I am seeing.

Comment: I could almost reproduce the telnet issue, then I found my bug... if you disconnect from breanstalk, it resets the reserved jobs.  I was piping the beanstalk command into nc localhost 11300, which disconnected after the response.  Running reserve again reserved the same job.  Running reserve on two different connections, and keeping them connected, reserved two different jobs.  So:  is the app disconnecting after reserving jobs?

Comment: No, it's definitely not. You are correct, you need to stay connected- disconnecting from beanstalk will put the job back into the queue for available jobs.

Comment: Andras how did you resolve this? I'm having a similar problem but using Redis as the queue server?

Comment: @MattHumphrey my bug was in the testing methodology -- I was disconnecting from beanstalkd, which reset the reserved tasks into an unreserved and available state, allowing them to be reserved again.  From what little I know of Redis, it publishes a notification and the workers grab the tasks, but I don't know how mutual exclusion is done.

Comment: Yeh it was redis that was the issue. Switched to beanstalkd and had no issues!

Answer (score 3):

Since you are running with Laravel, verify your `queue.php` configuration file.

Change the **ttr** value from 60 (default) to something else that is better for you.

```
    'beanstalkd' => array(
        'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
        'host'   => 'localhost',
        'queue'  => 'default',
        'ttr'    => 600, //Example
    ),
```